# how to find element of specified location found with action chains

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
actions= actionChains (driver)
element=actions.move_to_element_with_offset(text,30,40)
actions.click()
actions.perform()
```

with this code I could click on desired box now i wanna found that element
any idea?

Comment: could you explain bit more

Comment: by this code i can click on my desired element but how can i get more element data out of it?

Answer (score 0):

As per java docs http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html Actions not returns any webelement to retrieve information out of it.